# MulticastDelegate and Exception handling: is it possible to wrap it all generically?

Tags: c#, .net

When calling a Multicast Delegate one should use GetInvocationList to call one by one the delegate:

```
public void IterateAll()
{
    if( _doExecute != null )
    {
        foreach( ExecuteCallback doSingleExecute in _doExecute.GetInvocationList() )
        {
            try
            {
                doSingleExecute();
            }
            catch
            {
                // This delegate threw an exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to genericize this so as to go back to one single call by wrapping this iteration so as to hide it and so that one could call only once again the whole multicast delegate ? This would be closer to the intentional level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public static void CallAllAndCatch(this Action self)
{
    if (self == null)
        return;

    foreach (Action i in self.GetInvocationList()) {
        try { i(); }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Note that you *can* use generics if you find yourself doing this a lot with e.g. `EventHandler<T>`, but you cannot do this generically for *any* delegate of *any* type since delegate types cannot be assigned between each other, even if they are compatible, and there is no mechanism when defining a generic method to restrict a specific generic parameter to be a delegate with a specific signature.  (I *think* delegates with identical signatures are considered compatible types starting with .NET 4.)

For the `EventHandler<T>` approach:

```
public static void CallAllAndCatch(this EventHandler<T> self, object sender, T args)
    where T : EventArgs
{
    if (self == null)
        return;

    foreach (EventHandler<T> i in self.GetInvocationList()) {
        try { i(sender, args); }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

If you don't mind throwing performance and compile-time type checking down the tube, you can do this, which will work with any delegate type:

```
public static void CallAllAndCatch(this Delegate self, params object[] args)
    where T : EventArgs
{
    if (self == null)
        return;

    foreach (Delegate i in self.GetInvocationList()) {
        try { i.DynamicInvoke(args); }
        catch (MemberAccessException) { throw; } // A type of something in args isn't compatible with the delegate signature.
        catch (TargetException) { throw; } // The delegate itself is invalid.
        catch { } // Catch everything else.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for all these code snippets will study them carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Hmya, this is very fishy.  Catching an exception and handling it only really works well when you can restore the program's state so that it looks like the exception never happened.  That is *completely* impossible to do for a MulticastDelegate.

It's contract is that you have no idea what kind of code subscribed an event handler for it.  If that completely unknown code throws an exception and didn't handle itself, you have no guess at all how to restore state.  The event handler might have done a bunch of work, mutating state, then died somewhere near the end.  You have no hope of un-doing the 'bunch of work' parts, that code is unknown to you.  It might have been written months or years after you wrote your code.

Really Bad Idea, don't do this.

Comment: OK will think about it and will come back one day to this :)

Comment: The event wrapper should either rethrow, or else throw a wrapped exception, but that doesn't mean it shouldn't let the other delegate invocations complete before it does so.

Answer (score 1):

Is the type of the delegate fixed? You'll need to either use quite a bit of reflection, or you need to implement one version for each possible parametercount just like there is one Action<...> type for it.

Should look similar to this(untested notepad code):

```
  public static Action WrapAction(Action a)
  {
   var invList = ((MultiCastDelegate)a).GetInvocationList();

   for (int i = 0; i < invList.Length; i++)
   {
    invList[i] = ()=>{try invList[i] catch {...} });
   }
   return (Action)MulticastDelegate.Combine(invList);
  }
```

And you probably need to add special case handling for single cast delegates.

Comment: You can actually just call `a.GetInvocationList()`.  Single-cast delegates will return a one-element array containing just themselves.